# Is the module Menu translation necessary at all?

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I am developing a Drupal 7 multidomain - multilanguage site. I have installed [Menu Translation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1113982) module, but it is a nightmare to have dozens of items. But, in fact, it is not necessary at all. You can create menu in original language, and then use t() in a module to get all the text strings translated on the fly. Even you can have a very simple module in which you extract all the items in the menus.

Sincerely, I would have preferred to handle the site in that way, now there is no come back and it is a nightmare of a management.

Comment: yes it is a nightmare, what i like to do if having a fixed language menu per language. But in theory if you create a custom menu with hook_menu in a module (in theory) you can translate its title, i do not know if applies when create a menu in the interface

Comment: Menu translate module is to translate custom menus. Multilingual sites are always a nightmare.